# Can't Post data containing $ in a key to Firebase

Tags: firebase

I'm attempting to post some data into Firebase (relative part of the URL is /messages.json). The following request content:

```
{"gsx$enddate":"sometime"}
```

Gives the following error:

> Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value. Perhaps you're using invalid characters in your key names.

This is valid JSON however. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firebase Using Floating-Point Number as Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113401/firebase-using-floating-point-number-as-key)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's supposed to be a valid JSON but it seems like it's a limitation for FireBase

From [FireBase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#data_tree):

> Character Set Limitations
>
> Note that URLs used to construct Firebase references may contain any
> unicode characters except:
>
> - `.` (period)
> - `$` (dollar sign)
> - `[` (left square bracket)
> - `]` (right square bracket)
> - `#` (hash or pound sign)
> - `/` (forward slash)

Comment: Also, when I get data from Firebase it changes symbols `&` and `=` to unicode codes. Do u know what for?

Comment: Correct! And also a very Important point to be noticed here is: Sometimes developers use the Email_Id from Authentication to make a Key in the DB. Thats when this error can strike again. Cause just like its accepted Json, ther are also accepted Email_Id characters... BUT.. that are limited by Firebase for Key Values & hence Paths.

Comment: is `+` character valid?

Comment: `+` is a valid character. You can use it in your self-generated IDs. The link to the documentation has changed to: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits#data_tree