# Another form of Object literals in JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, firebase

I'm trying to figure out how to make this work:

```
var emails = $("#register_Email").val();
var split = emails.split("@");
var username = split[0];
var first = $("#register_FirstName").val();
var last = $("#register_LastName").val();
var phone = $("#register_PhoneNumber").val();

ref2.set({
   username: {
      active: true,
      email: emails,
      first_name: first,
      last_name: last,
      phone: phone,
      role: "technician"
    }
});
```

I can get all of the variables but the problem is I want to pass it into the set() method as seen above. The name of the whole node should be the value of the username, not the word username.

I've tried using literals in this way:

```
ref2.set({
   [username]: {
      active: true, 
      email: emails,
      first_name: first,
      last_name: last,
      phone: phone,
      role: "technician"
    }
});
```

But that doesn't work. It just crashes saying I can't pass `[` or `]` as variable names.

[image]

Comment: Your code works fine for me. The upper portion. You may want to give us more details on the error. your browser shouldn't crash because of your code. it should throw an error in console.

Comment: @Sean_A91: There is no error, the code just doesn't do what OP wants. "The name of the whole node should be the value of the username, not the word username.". i.e. for `username = "John"`, OP wants `{ John: { ... } }` and not `{ username: { ... } }`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON, which is always a string representation of an object (with a format similar to object literal syntax).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't do it with object literal. But you can remember that `foo.bar` is equivalent to `foo['bar']`, and write this instead:

```
var opts = {};
opts[username] = {
      active: true,
      email: emails,
      first_name: first,
      last_name: last,
      phone: phone,
      role: "technician"
    };
ref2.set(opts);
```

Comment: I just realized I can't accept emails with periods `.` in them... ha..ha..ha. For instance, I can't accept an email with `name.last@service.com` because of the period in the prefix. But this works. Thanks! Will make correct answer when it will let me

Comment: Why couldn't you accept emails with periods in them? If user is `name.last`, then object will be `{ "name.last": .... }`. You will not be able to access the data using `opts.John.Doe`, but you can still do it using `opts['name.last']`.

Comment: check out the edit with the image, its has to do with how Firebase handles this sort of thing

Comment: That is Firebase error, not JavaScript. I missed the [tag:firebase] tag, sorry. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363052/cant-post-data-containing-in-a-key-to-firebase). You can probably encode `username` some way - make it hex, transform periods to Japanese periods, use IDs with a lookup table...

Comment: Most commonly the `.` in email addresses is replaced with a `,` when using the email address as a Firebase key. There are many other encodings possible, but that is the convention.