# Firebase push key - allowed characters

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am wondering what kind of characters are allowed in the push key. Does it generate also a symbol underscore(_)? I always get a push key with letters with -.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Push keys use a modified Base64 alphabet:

```
-0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

They are comprised of a timestamp and a random value. The algorithm is described [here](https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11).

With Firebase keys in general, there is a small set of illegal characters and they are listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20363114/6680611):

> Character Set Limitations
>
> Note that URLs used to construct Firebase references may contain any
>   unicode characters except:
>
> - . (period)
> - $ (dollar sign)
> - [ (left square bracket)
> - ] (right square bracket)
> - # (hash or pound sign)
> - / (forward slash)

Comment: Actually, a blank space ' ' is also not valid.

Comment: Wanted to call out that `:` is also an acceptable value for a key, but is not going to be part of a "push key" (generated by `push`)