# Will Firestore Auto Generated ID contain _ underscore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple logic that combines 2 firestore ids with _, i.e. id1_id2. And when retrieving the composite key I split it using _. Therefore, is it possible for the auto generated id of Firestore to contain _ underscore, therefore ruining my simple logic in splitting with _ underscore?

I am using Firestore with Angular through [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2).

A simplified snippet.

`constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
   const id1 = this.afs.createId();
   const id2 = this.afs.createId();
   const compositeKey = id1 + '_' + id2;
}`

I need compositeKey because I want to achieve [an example in here](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/advanced-firestore-nosql-data-structure-examples/) by a Google Developer Expert: example `relationships/{followerID_followedID}`. There are other possible approaches to achieving the same outcome. However, in following the tutorial that teaches using compositeKey, I would like to understand is there no conflict in the use of _ underscore for splitting the 2 ids?

[image]

The compositeKey is not used for direct querying in Firestore. It is used for url routing. I have a route call `localhost:4200/relationship/follwerId_followId`

I would read for `relationship/:id` in Angular, next split by _ underscore, and lastly query `.collection('user_profile').doc(followerId)`  and  `.collection('user_profile').doc(followedId)` to show the profile of both users in a single page.

Comment: Please edit your question to include some code that shows how you're generating the IDs, and what exactly you're doing that requires them to be concatenated like this.  There might be a better way of getting your work done that doesn't depend on implementation details of Firestore.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for responding to my query. Just added a simplified snippet.

Comment: Yes, I understand you are concatenating two IDs.  My question is why you feel like you need to do this.  Are you using them in a query?  What's purpose does this serve?

Comment: Not using them in firestore query. Using them to manipulate url routing. Which means that I have an application that has url localhost:4200/relationship/followerId_followedId it will display all the information of follower and followed.

Comment: Why do you need an underscore delimiter there? You could just make them separate path components.

Comment: @DougStevenson did you mean localhost:4200/follower/followerId/followed/followedId ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172439/discussion-between-choopage-jek-bao-and-doug-stevenson).

Comment: Yes, I think that would work for you, and you wouldn't be depending on implementation details of Firestore.

Comment: @DougStevenson to clarify, you mean that there would not be any case of Firestore Auto generated id containing _ underscore correct?

Comment: Assuming that I do not want to separate path component. I want to concat the two Ids and use in a single path component. And in my url delimit it. What would be the right delimiter to use for 2 firestore ids?

Comment: Don't delimit them at all.  Just concatenate them directly.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am using your suggestion. However, I would like to uds that auto generated id of Firestore does not contain forward slash? Am I correct? https://stackoverflow.com/q/50691658/3073280

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that you can do is find a format for your data that allow you to know 100% sure that the pattern is not going to be duplicated randomly by Firebase.

Firestore keys use a modified Base64 alphabet like they did with Firebase Realtime Database:

```
-0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

They are achieved from a timestamp and a random value. you can find the algorithm [here](https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11).

There is a small set of not allowed characters for Firebase and they are listed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20363114/6680611):

> Character Set Limitations
>
> Note that URLs used to construct Firebase references may contain any
> unicode characters except:
>
> - . (period)
> - $ (dollar sign)
> - [ (left square bracket)
> - ] (right square bracket)
> - # (hash or pound sign)
> - / (forward slash)

Comment: This is not correct.  Firestore random keys are not the same as Realtime Database random keys.

Comment: My bad then. Sorry @DougStevenson . Could you provide us the way that the Firestore keys are generated?

Comment: I'm sure you can discover this for yourself by digging around in the source code for one of the many client libraries.  But it's worth noting that the SDK doesn't give you any guarantees or contracts about what to expect in these IDs, other than that they are valid document IDs.  Dependence on implementation details is a pretty bad idea, especially for a product that's still in beta.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/tree/master/packages/firestore