# Does Firestore auto generated id contains forward slash /

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore auto generated ID for my url path segment. It is separated by forward slash /.

For example, localhost:4200/follower/followerId/followed/followedId.

Both followerId and followedId are using Firestore auto generated id. 
My url path segment (using Angular) which separates url using forward slash such that localhost:4200/follower/:id/followed/:id

**Therefore, does Firestore auto generated id contains forward slash?**

Comment: no it does not generate with slash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible for a collection ID or document ID to contain a slash.  It's not a valid character.

Please see the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) for more details.