# how to submit to firestore a document that in the name of the document there is a "/" in python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, document

when i write to firestore only a name like: 'name' it adds that document but if i write na/me insted it will give me this error: ValueError("A document must have an even number of path elements") did anyone have this problem and has a answer for me??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Document IDs cannot contains `/`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50691658/does-firestore-auto-generated-id-contains-forward-slash (and the docs linked from there).