# In legacy firebase, data with the plus ('+') character as Key can't be deleted

Tags: javascript, firebase

I haven't migrated to the new firebase plan yet. But in the old firebase system, I found the data key can't contain the 'plus' sign ('+') besides the [document](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17113734/1613961) mentioned invalid characters. I found the problem when I tried to delete the data w/ the kind of key but failed ( Use `Firebase.remove()` ).

Here is what I reproduce the issue.

1. Use the default firebase rule

   {
     "rules": {
               ".read": true,
               ".write": true
           }
   }
2. Insert one data with **Key / Value** as **++ / ff** separately.
3. In the javascript code side, run this code.

   ```
   var s = 'https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com';
   var dd = new Firebase(s + '/++');

   dd.remove( function(error) {
       if (error) {
           console.log('failed');
       } else {
           console.log('succeeded');        
       }
   });
   ```

After running the code, program will run into the callback block which includes `console.log('succeeded');`. But the data ( **++ / ff** ) still be there.

Comment: I just entered a key `witha+` in both the legacy Firebase dashboard (www.firebase.com) and the new Firebase console (console.firebase.google.com) without problems. If you're having problems, it is better if you share the code that is giving problems or the steps how you got the problems.

Comment: Thanks @Frank van Puffelen, I'll try it again winthin 2 or 3 days. But what I mentioned might be a little unclear, I can add the data with '+' Key, but when I sent a `Firebase.remove` command, the data can't be deleted.

Comment: Without seeing [minimal, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we're just guessing as to what causes it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/38559661');

ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.key(), snapshot.val());
});

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Adding child');
  ref.child('++').set(true);
},2000);

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log('Removing child');
  ref.child('++').remove();
},4000);
```

Working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/dowuho/edit?html,js,console

Comment: @Thanks Frank, I need to use `.child()` instead of a complete url path.